# "Secondary spirals" within Fermat spirals

Tags: geometry

So I've been playing around with Fermat spirals recently, and I noticed that depending on how hard you look at one, each point has one or more "secondary spirals" coming off of it. Below is a link to a diagram I made illustrating this.

My question is: what's up with those? How can I get the dot indices or dot coordinates to draw these secondary spirals?

[A diagram I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vfvA.png)

[image]

Comment: I have learned that these secondary spirals are called "parastichies".

Comment: Without saying that it is the same thing, I see a certain similarity with the figures, especially the last one, given in a recent question of mine (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2127476)

Comment: Indeed with the keyword "parastichies", one can find very interesting sites for example, concerning "phyllotaxy" (another keyword):(http://www.science.smith.edu/phyllo/Applets/Spiral/Spiral.html#)

Answer (score 1):

Adding (or subtracting) a fibonacci sequence number to the index of any dot will move you one dot along a secondary spiral. In my case, the numbers that worked best are 21 and 34.

Thanks to a guy in ##mathematics on IRC for the suggestion :)