# How to make a geodesic dome 2V?

Tags: geodesic

I am trying to make a geodesic dome 2v in Solidwork just for fun.

I use this dome calculator : http://www.domerama.com/calculators/2v-geodesic-dome-calculator/

[image]

The problem is once I start the assembly, the first joint doesn't allign properly.

Is the calculator right ? I tried other calculators and they gave me the same results. What am I doing wrong ?

Here is the assembly made with sheet metal bending & 2x4 wood in solidwork:

So the **red bend is at 15.86 degrees** and the **blue bend is at 18 degrees**

[image]

**See the little hub at the bottom right of the picture ? It should fit perfectly with the B and A strut!**

Here is the **6 ways** hub :

[image]

Here is the **5 ways** hub:

[image]

**Take note that all the strut are at the same distance into the hub so the ratio is respected.**

What is wrong with my method ?

Comment: Please, could you explicitate what you mean when you say "the first joint doesn't align properly." ? 1) Which joint are you thinking to and 2) "doesn't align with what" ?

Comment: A link among many others, with original answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031875/math-for-a-geodesic-sphere/3033370#3033370

Comment: The strut A and B shiuld fit properly into the hub socket. See bottom right of the second picture.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the dihedral angles should be (in decimal degrees) :

> $$18.03° \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \  22.46°$$

I find back your first angle but the second one is indeed in disagreement with your $15.86°$...

How did I obtain this result ?

This geodesic dome is a half of a volume called [Pentakis icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentakis_icosidodecahedron)

[image]

that I have been able to "construct" using the rich data found in
http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/PentakisIcosidodecahedron.txt
but with a treacherous aspect, the points are not on a same sphere ! It took me some time before understanding and correcting it...

The following Matlab program that has allowed me to draw the figure and obtain the angles (think to scroll it) uses classical formulas with cross product and dot product :

- The normal to triangular face $ABC$ is given by $\vec{n}=\vec{AB} \times \vec{AC}.$
- The angle $a$ between two (normalized) normals is such that $\cos(a)=\vec{n_1}.\vec{n_2}.$

> ```
> %Pentakis Icosidodecahedron 
> % http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/PentakisIcosidodecahedron.txt
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal;
> C0 = sqrt(5 * (5 - 2 * sqrt(5))) / 5
> C1 = sqrt(10 * (5 - sqrt(5))) / 10
> C2 = (6 * sqrt(5) + sqrt(2 * (85 - sqrt(5))) - 16) / 19
> C3 = sqrt(10 * (5 + sqrt(5))) / 10
> C4 = (7 - 5 * sqrt(5) + sqrt(2 * (125 + 41 * sqrt(5)))) / 19
> C5 = sqrt(10 * (5 - sqrt(5))) / 5
> T=...
> [[0.0, 0.0,  C5];[0.0, 0.0, -C5];[ C5, 0.0, 0.0]
> [-C5, 0.0, 0.0];[0.0,  C5, 0.0];[0.0, -C5, 0.0]
> [ C2, 0.0,  C4];[ C2, 0.0, -C4];[-C2, 0.0,  C4]
> [-C2, 0.0, -C4];[ C4,  C2, 0.0];[ C4, -C2, 0.0]
> [-C4,  C2, 0.0];[-C4, -C2, 0.0];[0.0,  C4,  C2]
> [0.0,  C4, -C2];[0.0, -C4,  C2];[0.0, -C4, -C2]
> [ C0,  C1,  C3];[ C0,  C1, -C3];[ C0, -C1,  C3]
> [ C0, -C1, -C3];[-C0,  C1,  C3];[-C0,  C1, -C3]
> [-C0, -C1,  C3];[-C0, -C1, -C3];[ C3,  C0,  C1]
> [ C3,  C0, -C1];[ C3, -C0,  C1];[ C3, -C0, -C1]
> [-C3,  C0,  C1];[-C3,  C0, -C1];[-C3, -C0,  C1]
> [-C3, -C0, -C1];[ C1,  C3,  C0];[ C1,  C3, -C0]
> [ C1, -C3,  C0];[ C1, -C3, -C0];[-C1,  C3,  C0]
> [-C1,  C3, -C0];[-C1, -C3,  C0];[-C1, -C3, -C0]];
> for k=1:42
>     T(k,:)=T(k,:)/norm(T(k,:));%all points are now on the (unit) sphere !
> end;
> n=@(p,q,r)(cross(T(q,:)-T(p,:),T(r,:)-T(p,:)));%normal to face (p,q,r)
> for k=1:42
>     text(T(k,1),T(k,2),T(k,3),num2str(k));
> end;
> n1=n(7,1,21);n1=n1/norm(n1);
> n2=n(7,1,19);n2=n2/norm(n2);
> n3=n(1,21,25);n3=n3/norm(n3);
> a12=acos(n1*n2')*180/pi % angle at red junction
> a13=acos(n1*n3')*180/pi % angle at blue junction
> for p=1:42
>     for q=p+1:42;
>         no=norm(T(p,:)-T(q,:));%the two lengths are 0.618 and 0.5465
>         if abs(no-0.618)<0.005 || abs(no-0.5465)<0.005
>            c='r';
>            if abs(n-0.618)<0.005; 
>               c='b'
>            end;
>            I=[p,q];
>            plot3(T(I,1),T(I,2),T(I,3),c);
>         end;
>     end;
> end;
> view([-4,0]);
> figure(2);hold on;axis equal;
> x=T(:,1);y=T(:,2);z=T(:,3);
> K=convhull(x,y,z); % convex hull
> for k=1:80
>    I=K(k,:);colo=0.5+0.5*rand(1,3);
>    fill3(T(I,1),T(I,2),T(I,3),colo,'edgecolor','none');alpha(0.9)
> end;
> ```

[image]

Remark : one of the lengths is equal to $\Phi -1$ ($\Phi$ = Golden Ratio)

Comment: I understand that the formula for finding the side length of the equilateral triangles is your radius multiplied by Phi - 1, but how is the 0.5465 value calculated for determining the equal sides to the isosceles triangle?

Comment: if abs(no-0.618)<0.005 || abs(no-0.5465)<0.005

Comment: @mkinson I have an answer: it is $\sqrt{(C_3-1)^2+C_1^2} \approx 0.5465$ i.e. the distance between  vertices $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,C_3,C_1)$ (among others vertices, I have looked for the simplest ones). I have attempted to simplify a little the expression above in order to express it as a function of $\Phi$ but with no avail...

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie, on another site I found that a simplistic method of finding the side lengths of the triangles in a geodesic dome require multiplying the radius by phi-1 for the equilateral triangles, and that 0.5465 value by the radius for the isosceles triangles with phi-1 * r for the base. Never understood where that value came from.

Comment: @mkinson Very interesting. I will attempt to make the connection with the rather complicated value I gave you.

Comment: @mkinson I have simplified the expression I gave you; I obtain : $\sqrt{2-2\sqrt{\frac{\Phi}{\sqrt{5}}}} \approx  0.546533057825343...$

Comment: Thank you @Jean Marie! That is exactly what I was trying to find.

Comment: You can simplify that number further eliminating Phi entirely with sqrt(2 - sqrt(2 + 2/sqrt(5)))

Comment: @mkinson Right! May I ask you why you are interested into geodesic domes ? On my side, I had noticed them before trying to answer to the question of the OP as a cousin structure of the zonotopes: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2127476.

Comment: I am considering designing a geodesic home. I saw a bunch of fantastic design ideas, one including dozens of preformed triangle frames roughly 81.9 cm along the base.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the hub!

The construction of the hub must be made out from any hexagon... each Vertice/Hub has angle in its construction. I finally found a calculator that gives the information for the hub:

[image]

http://acidome.ru/lab/calc/#1/1_Piped_D200_2V_R6_beams_150x50