# Visualizing A Flattened $2v/3v$ Geodesic Dome

Tags: geometry, geodesic

I had a really nifty mathematic/art project idea and was wondering how flattening a partial sphere made of triangles could look.  From what I can just visually see it seems like I can take the face triangle and "make a star" out of them with one common vertex at the top, but are there any other ways I could layout the triangles so they could assemble in this way, i.e. more of a spiral or something "organic" that doesn't appear to be made from 1-2 components?  I'm leaning toward no but if there is, what resource could help me figure out what 2d "box designs" I could come up with?  I'm about $10$ years removed from my math theory BS so I'm a bit rusty, but hopefully not totally inept at figuring things out.

[Cut me in '3/8' and make a box design out of me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMPRn.png)

Comment: This looks very much like a soccer ball with 12 pentagons (see http://www.numericana.com/answer/polyhedra.htm)

Comment: Like you I don't understand what "Cut me in 3/8 ..." means... What is the origin of this figure ?Besides, About geodesic domes, here is an answer I gave some time ago https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3514631

Comment: Maybe you can be interested by this MIT article https://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/ARTL_a_00144 paragraph "Goldberg Polyhedra and the Caspar-Klug construction"