# Boundary of a zonotope

Tags: geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I am currently learning about [zonotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron) but I am having troubles understanding the concept of it.

I know that a zonotope is defined as

$$\left\lbrace x : x=c +\sum_{i=1}^k \xi_ig_i, \xi_i \in \lbrack -1,1\rbrack, \forall i=1, \dots, k \right\rbrace$$

where $c$ is called the center and $g_i$ are the generators. As an example I tried to draw the zonotope with center $0$ and generators $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and obtained the two-dimensional zonotp with vertices

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

1. Is this correct? And if so, is there a smarter way to construct it than by testing all possible linear combinations of the generators with coefficients $\pm 1$?
2. A proof in my home work assignment states that "at the boundary of this zonotope we have at most one fractional $\xi_i$". Unfortunately, I don't see why this is true.

Comment: Some points are missing: $\binom{3}{1}$ and $\binom{3}{2}$ and their opposites.

Comment: A good site for zonohedra (in particular with respect to Minkowski sum) is [this one](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/ukraine/ukraine.html). See also an illustrated question of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2127476) whose first received answer said "look at zonohedra!"

Comment: Thanks, I missed these two points