# Tessellation of n-gons into parallelograms

Tags: geometry, polygons, tessellations

Which regular n-gons can be tiled by (or tessellated into) a *finite* number of non-overlapping parallelograms?

I have enumerated a few cases below where I know the answer:

- Case $n = 3$, there is evidently no solution for any triangle.
- Case $n = 4$, the square is already a parallelogram so that's trivial.
- Case $n = 6$, the regular hexagon admits a nice tessellation as follows:

[image]

- Case $n = 8$, I have found the following tessellation for a regular octagon, though perhaps there is a simpler one:

[image]

(please forgive the approximate geometric shapes, I am freehanding it to show the idea)

---

I am particularly interested in a solution for the regular pentagon and heptagon, though the fact they have no parallel "opposite" sides due to having an odd number of sides makes me feel like a tessellation shouldn't exist for these, but I have no proof of this.

Has this problem been studied or does anyone have any insights into how to approach it?

I have already seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127476/looking-for-references-about-a-tessellation-of-a-regular-polygon-by-rhombuses) which is more specific than mine as it requires rhombuses whereas I am satisfied with more general parallelograms.

Comment: The paper [Tiling polygons with parallelograms](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02187834) seems relevant for your question.

Comment: @VTand Indeed, I think Theorem 1 in that paper pretty much settles it, implying a regular n-gon is tileable if and only if n is even... and even provides a construction which does the octagon in 6 tiles whereas mine above has 9. Great find ,I think this can be posted as an answer if you'd like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper *Tiling polygons with parallelograms* (https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02187834), Section 3 states the following:

> The edges of the polygon can be partitioned into equivalence classes where two edges are in the same class if they are parallel. We call the equivalence classes *slope classes*.

> **Balance Condition.** In every slope class, $S$, the vector sum of all the (oriented) edges in $S$ is zero.

> **Theorem 1.** A convex polygon is tilable if and only if it respects the balance condition.

It follows that a regular $n$-gon is tilable if and only if $n$ is an even integer (and $n \geq 4$).