# Projections of zonohedra

Tags: geometry, projection, solid-geometry

I noticed that any generic orthogonal projection of a cube has exactly two crossings.
[image: Orthogonally projecting a cube onto a plane]
This led me to wonder about generalizations. A friend suggested I look at zonohedra.

A [zonohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonohedron) is the Minkowski sum of several line segments, called *generators*. This includes the cube, even-sided prisms, the truncated octahedron, and more. After playing around with some examples, we came across the following conjecture:

**Conjecture:** Any (generic) orthogonal projection of a zonohedron with $n$ generators has $2(n-2)$ crossings.

(By "generic" I mean to exclude the measure-zero set of projections for which two line segments coincide, resulting in a continuum of intersections.)

Is this conjecture true? I have no idea how to prove it; visualizing rotating complicated three-dimensional objects makes my head hurt. It's entirely possible that we just missed a counterexample.

We may also conjecture the converse:

**Conjecture:** If all generic orthogonal projections of a polyhedron have the same number of crossings, it is a zonohedron.

(Note that, combined with our first conjecture, this means that in this case the number of crossings must be even.)

Comment: (There's no "zonohedra" tag?)

Comment: Since zonohedra are projections of hypercubes into 3-space, I just realized that this question is the same as asking about projecting hypercubes into the plane. EDIT: Not quite, since zonohedra have fewer edges than the hypercube they came from.

Comment: I think there probably are counterexamples, actually…

Comment: See my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127476/looking-for-references-about-a-tessellation-of-a-regular-polygon-by-rhombuses).